# Central web login system for university

Tags: http, networking, proxy

We have 300 hosts in our LAN. They use a linux server as default gateway. We need to send all traffic through a server machine which would then forward it to internet.

I want to add a central login system, where all students need to login first to access internet. Unauthorized access will be redirected to a link. Process should be like this,

```
Student_Request-> Login -YES-> Internet
```

How can i implement this? i mean from where should i start? Is there any tools to control iptable kind of settings? And one thing, our server is running in linux.

Comment: Close this question and move it to [sf]

Comment: Keyword suggestion: "captive portal". That's what such systems are called. "<expletive deleted> annoyance" would also meet the latter criterion but give you less usable results ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [http proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server).  Very often, [squid-proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is used for this purpose.

If you are also looking for web content filtering, [Dansguardian](http://dansguardian.org/) supports per-user authentication and might do what you're looking for.

Comment: OP asks for all internet traffic, not all web traffic. A Gateway might be better.

Comment: OP is probably not a native English speaker.  I had to edit his post to get something understandable before it was migrated from Stack Overflow.  While not explicitly stated, he seemed to be most concerned with http

Answer (score 1):

I think, from your description, you should be looking at Network Access Control (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Access_Control). There are countless products (hardware, software) to choose but you may be interested to look at PacketFence (http://www.packetfence.org/home.html) an open source product which runs very nicely on Linux machines (prefers RedHat).